# expo stuck on loading screen without error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I run `expo start --ios` and the splash screen comes up and it shows the app loaded 100% but the simulator is stuck on loading. I have cleared the cache in the simulator and did a fresh npm install and have removed `package-lock.json` beforehand. I have googled it and i'm not using facebook login or anything to import expo. I don't know where this is coming from.

only 3 lines of code it spits out is:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Expo] //in yellow
at App.js:98:14 in componentDidMount //these are green
at [native code]:null in flushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

**app.js**

```
  async componentDidMount() {

    try {
      const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
      if (update.isAvailable) {
        await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
        // ... notify user of update ...
        await Updates.reloadAsync();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // handle or log error
      console.log(`update his an error ${e}`)
    }

    await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
      ssb_Bold: require('./assets/font/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf'),
      ssb_Regular: require('./assets/font/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf'),
      ssb_Light: require('./assets/font/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf'),
      ssb_SemiBold: require('./assets/font/Source_Sans_Pro/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf'),
      SimpleLineIcons: require('native-base/Fonts/SimpleLineIcons.ttf'),
      Ionicons: require('native-base/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf'),
      'Material Icons': require('native-base/Fonts/MaterialIcons.ttf'),
    });

    await firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user !== null) {
        this.setState({
          isLogged: true,
          loaded: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          isLogged: false,
          loaded: true
        });
      }
    })

    
  }
```

Comment: it looks based on your error message to be coming from this: `await Expo.Font.loadAsync({` -- you probably don't actually have anything called `Expo` imported. look here to see the correct way to import and use `Font` https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/

Comment: that fixed the error but a different error came up however this cause my current issue to get resolved. Thank you